# What is the precise relationship between vector space and vecctor field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, terminology, vectors, definition

I have looked up precise definition of a vector field and a vector space but I could not understand the relationship between them.

On wikipedia

A vector field is:

> Given a subset $S$ in $R^n$, a vector field is represented by a
>   vector-valued function $V: S → R^n$ in standard Cartesian coordinates
>   $(x_1, ..., x_n)$.

A vector space is:

> $(V, F, +, *)$ satisfying vector space axioms

Field and space sounds like the same thing...but apparently quite different in terms of their definition. What is the key relationship between these concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector space is the place where a vector field lives in.

More formally, a vector space is a set of vectors which satisfy some basic properties, such as the ability to add and multiply them.

A vector field is a specific function *defined on* part of all of the vector space.

For example, consider the example of $\Bbb{R^3}$ representing space with the Sun at the origin. Then imagine a vector field in $\Bbb{R^3}$ where each point has an arrow pointing toward the sun and representing the strength of the gravitational pull at that point.

It is very much analogous to the real number line versus a function defined on the real line.

Comment: Are manifolds considered vector spaces? I have often seen vector field being defined on manifolds. However, it is not clear how we can add vectors on say a sphere

Comment: one can add tangent vectors if they are tangent at the very same manifold's point

Comment: I like the last sentence a lot, nice analogy!

Comment: I disagree with the statement that a vector field is "defined on part or all of a vector space".  Vector fields are typically defined on manifolds, which are not themselves vector spaces.

Comment: @JimBelk I'm sure your point is true; I was going for a more basic distinction with Euclidean spaces in mind.